# CI resize function doesn't work after transfer to new webspace

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration

After developing a website on a private webspace, I now want to make it public and therefore transfered it to my publich webspace (same php.ini settings and same OS).
Now a specific function (the CodeIgniter resize function) which worked on the other webspace perfectly, quits before the end, and I don't know why.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');

$this->image_lib->initialize($config_1);
$this->image_lib->resize();
$this->image_lib->clear();


$this->image_lib->initialize($config_2);
$this->image_lib->resize();
$this->image_lib->clear();
//function quits here for no reason :/

$this->image_lib->initialize($config_3);
$this->image_lib->resize();
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

**//Update:**

I've tried to display errors by using `$this->image_lib->display_errors();` but it doesn't show any errors.

I've also tried to use but this still doesn't help.

PS: GD function (server side) is enabled.

I tried to change `$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';` to `gd` and then it worked, but the image quality is crap :/

**//Update 2:**

Found out the error only occurs on images that are bigger then 8 MB. I've checked the php.ini settings but they are correct (to support files up to 50MB and 5 minutes max input time).

Comment: I don't know if this will be of interest but: `if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
{
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}` and also `$this->image_lib->clear();`

Comment: The above were taken from https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html - the latter snippet is used in the context of a loop which, because you are calling the `resize` method several times might be relevant. It states `"The clear function resets all of the values used when processing an image. You will want to call this if you are processing images in a loop."`

Comment: @RamRaider that's old user guide link here is current one. http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Comment: @RamRaider & wolfgang1983 thx for the quick answears. I'm going to have a look at it today and let you know if it helped.

Comment: @RamRaider I've tried to clear the image_lib but it doesn't seem to help. Also I've tried to display the errors but no errors are displayed as well :/

Comment: Sounds like either a write-permissions issue server-side or you may be missing the GD2 library for Apache/PHP - check all your extensions, etc.

Comment: @LionelRitchietheManatee all set permissions are correct (checked it a few times) and the GD2 library is also correctly installed. If found out that images with size under 8MB or something are perfectly resized. It seems that the problem only occurs for bigger filesizes, even though the php.ini settings are correct :/

Comment: try using `ini_set('memory_limit','16M');`

Comment: @LionelRitchietheManatee thx for the response. Unfortunately the memory_limit is already set to 128M and it's still not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that it may be a problem with the installed `GD2` image library.
I installed `ImageMagick` on the server and changed the

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
```

to

```
$config['image_library'] = 'imagemagick';
```

and now it works perfectly.